# Does the DbContextHelper.SaveChanges() method carry out the SaveScope() asynchronously after performing baseSaveChanges()?

Tags: audit.net

[image]

I do want to clarify whether SaveScope() in the AuditContext is carried out **asynchronously** after base.SaveChages() in-order to avoid normal operation getting blocked????

If not is any way implement that requirement.....???

Comment: @thepirat000 I'm new to Audit.EntityFramework library.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you call your EF DbContext's `SaveChanges()` the audit will be saved after the operation runs on the database and the calls to the audit data provider will be synchronous.

Otherwise, if you call `SaveChangesAsync()`, the calls to your audit data provider will be async.

If you need a different behavior you can implement your own [data provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#data-providers), inheriting from the base `AuditDataProvider` or from an [existing data provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#data-providers-included) of your convenience.